# How can I get this Png for planes?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I use blender, I would like to export my objects (planes) to make trasparency on unity.

I use this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P1F8v1_bim8&t=672s

But this tutorial is for blender. It's very good, but not for Unity, I would like to know how to use this in Unity to make transparency. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Standard` shader and set the `Rendering Mode` to `cutout`.

[image]

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/shader-StandardShader.html

or older shaders

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/shader-TransparentCutoutFamily.html